# Xamarin: Cannot build clean Android Wear project in

Tags: android, xamarin, wear-os

**I am trying to create an Android Wear project with xamarin, but I cannot get my project to run.**
I updated all the packages to the latest version

My android wear project is a standalone app so I set the minimum SDK version to 23.

**These are the most important packages that I am using in my android wear project:**

- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Wearable: v42.1021.1
- Xamarin.Android.Wear: v2.0.1.1
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Wear: v26.1.0.1
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4: v26.1.0.1

**I always get the following exception at starting my project:**

```
1>obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor.java:8: error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
1>      android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnDismissedListener
1>                                                    ^
1>obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnPreSwipeListenerImplementor.java:8: error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
1>      android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnPreSwipeListener
1>                                                    ^
1>obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\wear\widget\SwipeDismissLayout_OnSwipeProgressChangedListenerImplementor.java:8: error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
1>      android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnSwipeProgressChangedListener
1>                                                    ^
1>Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
1>Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1>Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
1>Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1>3 errors
1> error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
1>      android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnDismissedListener
1>
1> error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
1>      android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnPreSwipeListener
1>
1> error: package android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout does not exist
1>      android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnSwipeProgressChangedListener
1>
1>Done building project "NormalWearTest.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
```

**This is the file where the problem is located (SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor.java):**

```
package mono.android.support.wear.widget;


public class SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor
    extends java.lang.Object
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer,
        android.support.wear.widget.SwipeDismissLayout.OnDismissedListener
{
/** @hide */
    public static final String __md_methods;
    static {
        __md_methods = 
            "";
        mono.android.Runtime.register ("Android.Support.Wear.Widget.SwipeDismissLayout+IOnDismissedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Wear, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor.class, __md_methods);
    }


    public SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor ()
    {
        super ();
        if (getClass () == SwipeDismissLayout_OnDismissedListenerImplementor.class)
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("Android.Support.Wear.Widget.SwipeDismissLayout+IOnDismissedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Wear, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] {  });
    }

    private java.util.ArrayList refList;
    public void monodroidAddReference (java.lang.Object obj)
    {
        if (refList == null)
            refList = new java.util.ArrayList ();
        refList.add (obj);
    }

    public void monodroidClearReferences ()
    {
        if (refList != null)
            refList.clear ();
    }
}
```

**I added the full code sample on [Github](https://github.com/kevingoos/NormalWearTest)**

Comment: Remove the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Wear` if you don't use it, after remove this package, it works fine on my side.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT looks to be the solution :)

Comment: Happy coding. :)

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT thx, if you want some extra points post it as an awnser than I can approve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Wear` package if you don't use it, after remove this package, it works fine on my side.

Comment: and what if its needed for WearableRecyclerView?